# Create structure fieldnames from array of numbers

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a dataset that I would like to categorise and store in a structure based on the value in one column of the dataset. For example, the data can be categorised into element 'label_100', 'label_200' or 'label_300' as I attempt below:

```
%The labels I would like are based on the dataset
example_data = [repmat(100,1,100),repmat(200,1,100),repmat(300,1,100)];
data_names = unique(example_data);

%create a cell array of strings for the structure fieldnames
for i = 1:length(data_names)
    cell_data_names{i}=sprintf('label_%d', data_names(i));
end

%create a cell array of data (just 0's for now)
others = num2cell(zeros(size(cell_data_names)));

%try and create the structure
data = struct(cell_data_names{:},others{:})
```

This fails and I get the following error message:

**"Error using struct
Field names must be strings."**

(Also, is there a more direct method to achieve what I am trying to do above?)

Comment: Use `cell2struct(others,cell_data_names)` instead of `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `struct`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html),

> `S = struct('field1',VALUES1,'field2',VALUES2,...)` creates a
>       structure array with the specified fields and values.

So you need to have each value right after its field name. The way you are calling `struct` now is

```
S = struct('field1','field2',VALUES1,VALUES2,...)
```

instead of the correct

```
S = struct('field1',VALUES1,'field2',VALUES2,...).
```

You can solve that by concatenating `cell_data_names` and `others` vertically and then using `{:}` to produce a comma-separated list. This will give the cells' contents in column-major order, so each field name fill be immediately followed by the corresponding value:

```
cell_data_names_others = [cell_data_names; others]
data = struct(cell_data_names_others{:})
```